# "npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near", while installing express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting this error while installing express.js, can anyone let me know how to resolve this error?

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
'..."~0.3.0","mocha":"~1.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:     npm ERR!    
C:\Users\sm445\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-03T20_38_46_529Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

After that, try again to install express.js.